# How to eliminate emacs -Q startup lag

Tags: debugging

I'm trying out emacs. With no `.emacs` file and starting emacs 26.1 with `emacs -Q` on Debian 10, it takes two seconds for the welcome screen to show up. Before the welcome screen, there is a message "Loading .../00debian.el (source)...done". The "done" part shows up right away; I didn't have to wait for the word "done".

When this disappears, the welcome message shows up. I can press a key to get rid of it but this lag is disorienting.

How do I remove this lag?

---

Just to make sure the `00debian.el` isn't the source of the delay, I deleted the file entirely. Now the message doesn't show up but the lag is still there.

Comment: AFAIK with `-Q` the `00debian.el` should not be loaded.  Any chance you were actually typing `emacs -q` (with lowercase `q`)?  Also, please indicate if you're running Emacs in GUI mode inside a text terminal (and if so, which text terminal): my crystal ball tells me it might be related to `xterm-extra-capabilities`.

Comment: @Stefan Nope. Definitely the capital Q. Also tried --quick with same results. I'm using terminal emacs, in a Linux installation that just displays the console. No xterm or any other terminal programs.

Comment: @Stefan FYI, SSH'ing into Linux also shows the same lag.

Comment: Sounds like a bug (Debian? Emacs?). If you don't get a good answer here then maybe submit an Emacs bug report (`M-x report-emacs-bug`) or a Debian bug report (?).

Comment: @ana: the "Linux console" *is* a text terminal.  And when "SSH'ing into Linux" you're most likely also doing it from within a text terminal.  So my crystal ball just seems more confident about its guess.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use a GUI Emacs? If you run `emacs -Q --batch --eval "(print 2)"`? For debugging, the strace output may be useful: run `sudo apt-get install strace` then `strace -ttt -o emacs.strace emacs -Q`, exit Emacs and upload `emacs.strace`.